# Shortcut for percentage increase and decrease involving odd numbers

Tags: percentages

Is there a shortcut to find $39\%$ of $234$? One way is to find $\frac{39}{100}\times234$. This involves multiplying decimal numbers. Second way is find $10\%$ which is $23.4$, and then $40\%$ which is $93.6$ and subtract $1\%$ which is $2.34$.

What I would like to know is there any other quicker way?

Thanks

Comment: Dividing them both by 10, and them multiplying them also works, and is simpler in some cases. 20% of 60 is 2 x 6 = 12